# RESTful way to sometimes require challenge

Tags: rest

We have a checkout page where the user enters their CC number, item they want to purchase, and they complete a challenge. When the form is submitted, the sever validates the challenge and then saves the payment and charges their card.

However, we want to change it to only prompt for the challenge when the person making the checkout is considered suspicious (and increase the difficulty of the challenge as they get more suspicious).

- checkout button is pressed (POST)
- server checks request data and compares it against previous checkouts
- server determines if challenge is needed, if so, client needs to complete this and send back to the server
- if challenge is not needed, checkout is accepted and CC is charged

What would be the RESTful way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What would be the RESTful way to do this?

How would you do it with web pages?

Probably - you would present the user with a form, the user would fill in the form and submit it.  If the user looks innocent, then you would process the checkout as is, and send back a response that represents the checkout action.

If the user looks suspicious, then rather than processing *that* form, you would send the user a response that says `we can't process your payment because you are suspicious; use this alternative form to make progress`.  The user would submit the alternative form, and then you would evaluate whether or not the user had met the security challenge.

That's the RESTful way to do it; you give the client forms to submit, and links to follow.  Clients that recognize the semantics provided in the representations can make progress, those that cannot stop.